# How to grab image file name as variable in Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, image, dom, google-tag-manager

My website has a lot of images and I want to grab the image file name from the HTML and pass it to Google Analytics.

My site code has:

```
<div class="picture-loading c-card__park">
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://......">
  <img alt="alt" src="https://..../BEL-1497.jpg?width=430&height=380...">
```

I need to build a variable that will grab just the image name (BEL-1497.jpg) from the img tag that will change each time a new image appears on screen.

Would this be as simple as creating a DOM Element variable using the CSS Selector and selecting img?

NOTE:
I have setup an Auto-Event Variable which does grab the image file name:
[image]

But I need it to grab *just* the file name, currently returns:

/getmedia/07f6ade8-c715-46f8-9963-33ba84449dbe/BEL-1497.jpg

When I just want:

BEL-1497

NOTE2: Was able to use custom JS variable:

```
function(){
  var url = {{Click URL}};
  var filename = url.substring({{Click URL}}.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  return filename;
}
```

which gives me: BEL-1497.jpg
Now just need to drop the file extension

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fname = "BEL-1497.jpg";
const splitted = fname.split('.');
const result = splitted.slice(0, splitted.length - 1).join('.');

console.log(result);

// OR

const result2 = fname.replace(/.\w+$/, '');

console.log(result2);
```